# XCUIApplication is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Ever since I update to Xcode 9  last weekI have been getting this error, however all my applications build and run successfully.  The apps work and run great I am just double checking if this will effect my apps to be able to run and launch  on iOS 8.0-11.0 still.

Comment: Your app doesn't use XCUIApplication (if it does, it can't get into the app store). It's for UI Tests only.